# awk printing the second to last record of a file

Tags: awk, record

I have a file set up like

```
Words on 
many line
%
More Words
on many lines
%
Even More Words
on many lines
%
```

and I would like to output the second to last record of this file where the record is delimited by `%` after each block of text.

I have used:

```
awk -v RS=\% ' END{ print NR }' $f
```

to find the number of records (1136). Then I did

```
awk -v RS=\% ' { print $(NR-1) }' $f
```

and

```
awk -v RS=\% ' { print $(NR=1135) }' $f
```

.
Neither of these worked, and, instead, displayed a record towards the beginning of the file and a many blank lines.
OUTPUT:

```
"You know, of course, that the Tasmanians, who never committed adultery, are
now extinct."
    -- M. Somerset Maugham


"The
is
what
that
```

This output had many, many more blank lines and contains a record near the middle of the file.

```
awk -v RS=\% 'END{ print $(NR-1) }' $f
```

returns a blank line. The same command with different `$(NR-x)` values also returns a blank line.

Can someone help me to print the second to last record in this case?
Thanks

Comment: `$ n` selects _field_; to select _record_ (usually but not here line) do like `awk -vRS=% 'NR==1135'` for a single file or combined files or `FNR` for one of multiple files. You could do both passes in one run like `awk -vRS=% 'FNR==NR{sel=NR-1} FNR==sel' filename filename`. But better use @dawg's one pass with two vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '{this=last;last=$0} END{print this}' file
```

Or, if you don't mind having the entire file in memory:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[NR-1]}' file
```

Or, if it is just line count (or record count) based, you can keep a rolling deletion going so you are not too piggish on memory:

```
$ seq 999999 | tail -2
999998
999999
$ seq 999999 | awk '{a[NR]=$0; delete a[NR-3]} END{print a[NR-1]}'
999998
```

---

If they are blocks of text the same method works if you can separate the blocks into delimited records.

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt" 
Words on 
many line
%
More Words
on many lines
%
Even More Words
on many lines
%
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk -v RS=\% '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[NR-1]}'

Even More Words
on many lines

$ echo "$txt" | awk -v RS=\% '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[NR-2]}'

More Words
on many lines
```

If you want to not print the leading and trailing `\n` you can do:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="%\n"} {a[NR]=$0} END{printf a[NR-2]}'
Words on 
many line
```

Finally, if you know the specific record you want to print, do it this way in awk:

```
$ seq 999999 | awk -v mrk=1135 'NR==mrk{print; exit}'
1135
```

---

If you want a random record, you can do:

```
$ awk -v min=1 -v max=1135 'BEGIN{srand() 
                                  RS="%\n"
                                  tgt=int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))
                                  } 
                            NR==tgt{print; exit}' file
```

Comment: This is getting close, I think, but the record can consist of any number of lines. There are some records with 1 line and some records with 100 lines.

Comment: What if I wanted to, instead of the second to last record, print a random record? That is, output a record anywhere between 1 and 1135?

Comment: Use awk to generate the random record. Something like: `$ awk -v min=1 -v max=1135 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}'` then use the last line there.

Answer (score 1):

Does the solution have to be with awk?  Just using head and tail would be simpler.

```
tail -2 file.txt | head 1 > justthatline.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `tail -2 file.txt | head -n 1`? This is creative, but you are missing the `-n` argument to `head`

Comment: they are not single lines, the line count in each record may vary from 1 line to 100 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this would be to use the BEGIN construct.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="%\n"; ORS="%\n"}(NR>=2){print}' file
```

RS and ORS set the input file and output record separators respectively.